# Problem with shorcuts using Alt key

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 17.10, shortcuts

I have a problem with shortcuts after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, and have no idea how to debug it.

Problem is following:
When I use shortcuts like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> it behaves as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> depending on which key was pressed first.

It's possible that is's only java problem (I have this behavior stably reproducible in CLion IDE, and unstable in others), but seems it's overall problem.

Is is some known issue, or is there any easy way to debug which presses/released events are happen?

**UPD:** Seams, I got the problem. Alt+Shift is set up as keyboard layout change shortcut. So, when shift is pressed, alt press changes layout and not delivered to applications, and visa versa if alt is already pressed, shift is not delivered. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your keyboard shortcuts in System Settings to make sure that they weren't changed?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure is this. Maybe it's important that Alt+Shift is setup as keybord layout change key.

Comment: I can add: 1) It is not related to Java, system application don't take it either, 2) It is still bugging if Ctrl-Shift is used to switch languages too. It looks to me that language switch combination disables any other combinations that contain it, like Ctrl-Alt-Shift-<Arrow> for me or Ctrl-Alt-L for @kunyavskiy.

Comment: It is well known bug - [see bug at launchpad 1245473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1245473). Ctrl+Shift is affected too. I "fixed" it by switch to MATE DE on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.