# 17.10. Disable LShift + RShift switching of keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, 17.10

I changed keyboard layout switching to Alt+Shift (with Tweaks). But I still have LShift+RShift switching behavior working with new one simultaneously.

How can I disable this double shift switch?

UPD:

```
glaz@glaz-pc:/etc/profile.d$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT=us,ru
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=,
glaz@glaz-pc:/etc/profile.d$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:alt_shift_toggle']
```

UPD (2017-11-15):
The problem is gone by itself. Probably after one of system updates.

Comment: Please show us the output of these two commands: `cat /etc/default/keyboard` and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` (Please edit your question and include the output there.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Done.

Comment: Nothing there which would explain why <LShift>+<RShift> would cause a layout switch. But I justed tested it myself, and see the same behavior, so it's probably a bug. Or a feature. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Well, yeh, it's a bad feature, because when you typing fast something like passwords in upper case with different hands, both shifts are pressed pretty often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone by itself. Probably after one of system updates.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the problem described in "[Problem with shorcuts using Alt key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971287)", a possible explanation might be that you have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> set up as keyboard layout change shortcut.

Comment: Nope. There is a different problem.