# How to make a keyboard shorcuts using 'windows/super' + 'alt' + letter

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, remapping

I'm trying to make keyboard shortcuts using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>something</kbd>, the problem is that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> sometimes behaves as just <kbd>Super</kbd> making shorcuts as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> same as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. but even worst, when I map it to a new shortcut (using input remapper) the result of the remap inherits behaviors of other shortcuts having same letters.

For instance in my computer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> and also <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Re pag</kbd> move the virtual desktop, from these three only the last is registered in *settings, keyboard shorcuts* (so no idea why they have that behavior in the two first cases)

If map <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> what I get when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is the virtual desktop moving to the left, instead a plain left arrow.

I have investigated a lot, tried additional layout options 'alt and win behavior' inside gnome tweaks, looked multiple post here:

[Problem with shorcuts using Alt key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971287/problem-with-shorcuts-using-alt-key)

[OS keyboard shortcuts conflict with apps keyboard shortcuts in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009352/os-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-apps-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-3)

It seems there is even a related bug in ubuntu:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473

Just wanted to know if there is any known work around? or if somebody can put a bit of light in this topic. Thanks!

pd: I use a custom keyboard layout that is changed using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (not same as in the bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a long time, updated Ubuntu to 23.04 and installed "input-remmaper" 2.0 from the source and configure it there, now it seems it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, have you tried to use `alt` + `super` + `letter` instead?

I've just customized a shortcut for opening my calculator as `alt` + `super` + `c` and it worked ok.

I would ask that in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: So you mean inverting the order? I'm using input remapper which takes the keystroke directly, so I don't write the keystrokes myself, I think super+alt and alt+super are the same modfifier, but I can also be completely wrong... how did you do your mappings?

Comment: In any case, just want to remark that the remapping technically works, cause super+alt+a now it makes the a behaves as an arrow, the problem is that it still behaves as a modified arrow stroke by super alt, so it moves the desktop instead of do the arrow move

Comment: I gave the bounty to you, cause other option was losing this XP for ever and for everyone, but this didn't solve my issue, if you are as interested on solving this question as I am, you can maybe post it bounty it again, but feel free.